# without adding height to header can we fix the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my CSS & HTML here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/433xyyt5/), where in header I use 50px height, Is there any way where I don't need to add height in header and still the layout should fit in all page

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#page {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use padding/margin

Comment: It will fit everywhere even if you dont add height, but what is your end goal?

Comment: I can't add padding because i have an image in banner which should fit the whole header

Comment: let me tell you what i understand,  irrelevant with header height, the header should fix to the top of the page? and your content should come after that?

Comment: yes, but now the problem is as i use  `height: calc(100% - 100px);` on my CSS so i have to give pixles in header which i can't do

Comment: @user2181397 No it won't fit, Is there any other way?

Comment: why do you give a height to the content and not to the header?

Comment: see the header, container and footer should fill the whole page without scrolling that;'s the reason i added height @madalinivascu

Comment: and why can't you add height to the header, what is stopping you?

Comment: what will happen if the content is larger then the page height ?

Comment: The way i see it, the header fits the pagewidth and height of its content perfectly, but if you wanna control the height of the header. i guess you should add a height. But as @madalinivascu asks .. why cant you add a height?

Comment: @madalinivascu if the content is larger then the page height then there will be scroller within that content only but the page should not be fixed without scrool, I hope these clear your doubts

Comment: @minal does flex supports MAC or all browsers

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Get the Outer height of the header
    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight();
    //Add the same height to the content as padding top.    
    $('#content').css('padding-top', headerHeight); 
});
```

Comment: these works good but when i minimize the page i need to reload the page to get the padding. Can it be resolved?

Comment: If page is reloading, this will execute, and it will behave same like loading. And why you want to reload the page while coming back from minimize. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the whole page vertically without specifying rows' heights, you may use `flex`.
In this example header and footer are also sticky, thanks to the `overflow: auto` on container's children (and `overflow: hidden` on the container itself).

```css
body {margin:0;padding:0;}
#page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page>* {
    overflow: auto;  
}
#header {
    background-color: red;
}
#footer {
    background-color: red;
}
#content {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does flex supports MAC or all browsers

Comment: @moidul-dargahi this is the current situation on CanIUse http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. The browser must know how you want it to show the header. If the header may be get longer in other situations, you can use min-height property instead of height. If you faced other problems, this a better way I think to implement your idea. 
Here is a CSS code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

#content {
    padding:100px 0;
    background: grey;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```